# Visual Studio Font Size Change

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2019

I'd like to change font size of the rectangled areas. I've changed font size from "local windows" but nothing has changed.

[image]

Comment: You can change those by modifying the *"[Watch, Local and Auto Tools Windows]"*. However it doesn't seem to affect the Call Stack Window. Also it seems to matter if you used a different value than the default on any of those windows individually. For example my *"Locals"* kept being stuck at 22pt font size until I reset both the *[Watch, Local, ..]* and the *"Locals Window"* to default.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try changing from **Use > tools > options > Environment -> Fonts** and Colors (Show settings drop down) and then  **Locals Window for properties window**